# Creating rule-based sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have a list each element of which consists of a list containing two strings and two integers:

```
lis = {{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"d", 3, "e", 4}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"c", 7, "d", 8}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}
```

I would like to create a new list that includes every member of `lis` whose first element starts with `"a"`:

```
res = {{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}
```

This would seem to be a simple task for `StringCases`, but I am not having much luck; suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Pick[lis, StringTake[lis[[All, 1]], 1], "a"]

Pick[lis, StringPart[lis[[All, 1]], 1], "a"]
```

> {{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}

Less elegantly readable ones that use `ToCharacterCode`:

```
Pick[lis, 
 First@ToCharacterCode@First@# == Sequence @@ ToCharacterCode["a"] & /@
   lis]

Pick[lis, 
 lis[[All, 1]] /. s_String -> ToCharacterCode[s] // Map[First], 
 Sequence @@ ToCharacterCode["a"]]
```

Answer (score 12):

Some options:

```
Pick[
 lis,
 StringStartsQ[lis[[All, 1]], "a"]
 ]
```

> `{{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}`

```
Select[lis, StringStartsQ[First[#], "a"] &]
```

> `{{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}`

```
Cases[lis, {_?(StringStartsQ["a"]), ___}]
```

> `{{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}`

Comment: Thank you for the options, I'll check which is faster with a large data set I have.

Comment: `:> m` in `Cases` is not necessary.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Alternate solutions using string patterns:

```
Pick[lis, StringMatchQ[lis[[All, 1]], "a" ~~ ___]]
```

> `{{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}`

```
Pick[lis, StringCases[lis[[All, 1]], "a" ~~ ___] // Map[Length], 1]
```

> `{{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}`

```
Pick[lis, StringPosition[lis[[All, 1]], "a" ~~ ___] // Map[MatrixQ]]
```

> `{{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}`

Answer (score 5):

A few additional variations:

```
Pick[lis, StringMatchQ["a*"]@lis[[All, 1]]]
```

> {{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}

```
Pick[lis, StringTake[lis[[All, 1]], 1], "a"]
```

> {{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}

```
Pick[lis, Order[#, "b"]& /@ lis[[All, 1]], 1]
```

> {{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}

Answer (score 2):

```
ReplaceAt[lis, _?(Not @* StringStartsQ["a"]) :> Nothing, {All, 1}]
```

{{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {3, "e", 4}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {7, "d",
8}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}

Comment: This is different from `res` in the OP?

Comment: Try with: `ReplaceAt[lis, _ -> (If[StringStartsQ[#[[1]], "a"], #, Nothing] &)@*
   List, {All, 0}]`

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `ReplaceAll`:

```
lis /. x : {___} /; StringQ[x[[1]]] :> If[StringStartsQ[x[[1]], "a"], x, Nothing]

(*{{"ab", 2, "c", 3}, {"ac", 5, "f", 6}, {"ad", 9, "c", 10}}*)
```

Comment: Why is it different from `res` in the OP?

Comment: Thanks, mate! :-)